# Can S3 now safely be used as origin for live video?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-live-streaming

I have seen that as of December 2020, AWS S3 now offers [strong consistency](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/)

That was previously a barrier to using S3 for live HLS, since you could not guarantee that a live.m3u8 manifest file (overwritten over and over to add the latest .ts segments on the end of it) would be served as expected. You may get a prior copy served, breaking the stream (eventual consistency).

With *strong* consistency, that is no longer the case as the latest .m3u8 will always be served and so that solves that problem.

I know AWS added MediaStore a while ago specifically for live video (since back then S3 could not be used for it, because of eventual consistency) and so is it simply they are not mentioning using standard S3 for live video to avoid taking users from that alternative system? Only the downside of using MediaStore is that has a quota limit of 25MB per object (unlike S3) so *it* could not be used for VOD files (like .mp4). So you'd have to use S3 for VOD files. And I'd like to use the same storage for all content, if possible.

Is anyone serving live HLS (or DASH) with S3 as its origin? Does it work successfully?

Comment: Have you had an issue with this in practice?  I can't think of an HLS player that isn't going to try to just fetch the playlist again if it's stale, and fetch the segment again if it isn't present.  The common players seem very forgiving.  Although, I'm using a CDN in front of the bucket, so that might be reducing some issues for me.

Comment: @Brad I haven't since I was always put off from using S3 because of that potential issue. As if the wrong .m3u8 was returned, a live stream would stall. If the segments were, say, 10 seconds, that shouldn't be an issue. As like you say, the .m3u8 should be requested again, and S3 shouldn't take that long to become consistent (in the past). But I figured with very short segment durations, that would be a realistic issue, and so should not use S3.